# How to store data in Array using Local storage in HTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="textstorage">
<button name="testbutton" onclick="myFunction()">send</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function myFunction(){
alert("dasd")
// Check browser support
var inp = document.getElementById("textstorage");
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("result", inp.value);
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("result");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("result");



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How to store multiple values in webpage using Array. Please help me.

Note: If i enter one value it replaces the previous value. I need like array stores all values.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: It replaces the previous value. I need both current and previous values.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage does not support arrays but only string values. It stores `key:value` pairs. Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to store arrays indirectly in a `LocalStorage` object.

For Example:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = "One";
arr[1] = "Two";
arr[2] = "Three";

localStorage["arr"] = JSON.stringify(arr);
var arrStored = JSON.parse(localStorage["arr"]);
```